# grep 2 words from specific csv column and count them

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to find a better way to complete the following grep/awk query. The below is a trivial example of the question.

I have gotten to this point with my regex:

```
grep -Po ^(?:[^,]+,\s?){7}(Want|Need) | awk -F ',' 'NR>=2{print $8}' | sort | uniq -c
```

My CSV file looks as follows:

```
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Want,Turbo,Good
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Selling,Turbo,Good
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Need,Turbo,Good
```

The above works to print the entire row with grep:

```
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Want
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Need
```

and I can then count values from column 8. My question is how do I write the grep/regex query to only return the group I have selected with regex.

eg:

```
Want
Need
```

The reason for this post is to purely understand a better way to use regex here. I know of other ways to do this.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. Also bear in mind the quote [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the PCRE `\K` assertion. From [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre):

> There is a special form of this construct, called \K (available since
> Perl 5.10.0), which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it
> had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $&.

So

```
$ grep -Po '^(?:[^,]+,\s?){7}\K(Want|Need)' file.csv
Want
Need
```

More generally, this kind of thing is done with a *lookbehind* assertion - however Perl doesn't support variable length lookbehinds, and neither does grep -P:

```
$ grep -Po '^(?<=(?:[^,]+,\s?){7})(Want|Need)' file.csv
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

See also [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: \K did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Note that the PCRE regexp specification is documented in the `pcrepattern` man page. There are some differences compared to perl regexps including for `\K` (though none that applies here). `\K` was added in PCRE 7.2.

Comment: can this be used with sed to replace the values? eg: want->value_1, need->value_2

Comment: @malkier11 any time you're considering using sed+grep you should be using awk instead.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `-P` is a non-standard (and optional and long considered experimental) option of the GNU implementation of `grep`, with which it uses libpcre (a standalone implementation of perl's regex) to do the matching¹

`libpcre` does come with its own `grep` command as example code (`pcregrep`), though it has now evolved into a full-fledged `grep` implementation, that for instance can be found in its own package on a few GNU/Linux distributions.

`pcregrep` has extended GNU `grep`'s `-o` non-standard option to take an optional numeric argument to output the corresponding capture group:

So here:

```
pcregrep -o1 '^(?:[^,]+,\s?){7}(Want|Need)'
```

Or you could use the real thing, which would also have the advantage of working even on systems that have neither GNU `grep` (or where GNU `grep` has been built without PCRE support) nor `pcregrep`:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(?:[^,]+,\s?){7}(Want|Need)/'
```

Note however that `perl`, by default doesn't decode the input as per the locale's text encoding like GNU `grep` does. In that specific case, where the text you're matching uses only characters from the portable character set, it's probably rather and advantage as it will still work even if the input's encoding differs from the locale.

If you wanted `perl` to decode text on input (and encode on output) as per the locale's encoding, you could add `-Mopen=locale`.

---

In your case though, there's not much that warrants perl regexps. All the perl operators you're using there have standard ERE operator equivalents (even BRE except for alternation).

- `(?:...)`: it's just perl/ERE `(...)` or BRE `\(...\)` without capturing.
- `+`: same in ERE, `\{1,\}` in BRE
- `?`: same in ERE, `\{0,1\}` in ERE
- `{7}`: same in ERE, `\{7\}` in BRE
- `(Want|Need)`: same in ERE (though with slight differences in behaviour when it comes to choosing sides of the alternation).
- `\s`: `[[:space:]]` in both BRE and ERE
- `^`, `[^,]`: same in BRE or ERE

`sed` is the tool to extract matching parts in a pattern (while `grep`, named after `ed`'s `g/re/p` command is to `p`rint the lines that match a `r`egular `e`xpression). Standard `sed` uses BREs, but most `sed` implementations support `-E` to switch to ERE (and that will be added to the next version of the standard).

So here, as an equivalent of the `perl` command above, you could also do portably:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -nE 's/^([^,]+,[[:space:]]?){7}(Want|Need).*$/\2/p'
```

Or without `-E`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/^\([^,]\{1,\},[[:space:]]\{0,1\}\)\{7\}\(Want\).*$/\2/p; t
                 s/^\([^,]\{1,\},[[:space:]]\{0,1\}\)\{7\}\(Need\).*$/\2/p'
```

Or to replace those `Want` or `Need` with something else:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,[[:space:]]?){7})(Want|Need)/\1Desire/'
```

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/^\(\([^,]\{1,\},[[:space:]]\{0,1\}\)\{7\}\)Want/\1Desire/; t
              s/^\(\([^,]\{1,\},[[:space:]]\{0,1\}\)\{7\}\)Need/\1Desire/
```

---

<sup>¹ since then, other implementations have added their own `-P` option to use `perl`-like regular expressions, not always using libpcre like ast-open's `grep` (which does support look-around assertions but not `\K`)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, are you able to give me an idea of how I could replace the values using sed. eg want->value_1, need->value_2. 

I understand how to do it with awk, more for my own curiosity.

Comment: @malkier11 see edit.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much for the detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using awk, so you don't need `grep` here.  You don't need `sort` or `uniq -c` either.  For example:

```
$ awk -v search=Want -F, '$8 ~ search { count[$8]++ };
    END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' input.csv 
    1   Want

$ awk -v search='Want|Need' -F, '$8 ~ search { count[$8]++ };
    END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' input.csv 
    1   Want
    1   Need
```

Or if you want it to print the matching lines too:

```
$ awk -v search='Want|Need' -F, '$8 ~ search { count[$8]++ ; print };
    END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' input.csv 
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Want,Turbo,Good
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Need,Turbo,Good
    1   Want
    1   Need
```

You can add case-insensitivity with GNU awk by adding `-v IGNORECASE=1` to the command line, and even add fancy feature like exact matches if you want:

```
$ awk -v search='want' -v exact=1 -v IGNORECASE=1 -F, '
    BEGIN {if (exact == 1) search = "^(" search ")$"};
    $8 ~ search { count[$8]++ ; print };
    END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' input.csv 
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Want,Turbo,Good
    1   Want
```

The following won't produce any output because while `ant` is in `Want`, it is not an exact match for the entire field 8:

```
$ awk -v search='ant' -v exact=1 -v IGNORECASE=1 -F, '
    BEGIN {if (exact == 1) search = "^(" search ")$"};
    $8 ~ search { count[$8]++ ; print };
    END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' input.csv
```

---

Note: there are obviously better ways of doing command-line option processing (e.g. with a [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getopt-Function.html) function or by writing a shell script wrapper to use the sh/bash built-in `getopt`), but using awk's `-v` option to set variables in awk from outside the script is easy and convenient for simple tasks like this.

BTW, awk also allows variables to be asssigned without using `-v` by adding them to the command line after the script itself (awk will interpret any argument of the form `x=y` as setting variable x to value y.  Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to use filenames with an `=` in them - maybe impossible, I can't remember if I ever found a solution to this other than "don't do that, then").

Unlike when using `-v`, though, these variables are **NOT** available in a `BEGIN {}` statement.  e.g. the following will match `ant` even though we're setting `exact=1`:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {if (exact == 1) search = "^(" search ")$"};
           $8 ~ search { count[$8]++ ; print };
           END { for (f in count) { printf "%5i\t%s\n", count[f], f}}' \
    search=ant IGNORECASE=1 exact=1 input.csv 
1896,Ranger,2021,State,Postcode,Surname,Industry,Want,Turbo,Good
    1   Want
```

From GNU awk's man page:

> If a filename on the command line has the form `var=val`
> it is treated as a variable assignment. The variable `var`
> will be assigned the value `val`. (This happens **after** any
> `BEGIN` rule(s) have been run.)
>
> Command line variable assignment is most useful for
> dynamically assigning values to the variables AWK uses to
> control how input is broken into fields and records. It is
> also useful for controlling state if multiple passes are
> needed over a single data file.

IMO, it's best to think of that as a legacy feature for compatibility with old awk scripts and to just use `-v`.

> ```
> -v var=val
> --assign var=val
> ```
>
> Assign the value `val` to the variable `var`, before execution
> of the program begins. Such variable values **are** available to
> the `BEGIN` rule of an AWK program.

(bold emphasis on "after" and "are" in the quotes above were added by me)

Comment: Assigning variables in the arg list isn't just legacy, its commonly used to assign values between files (e.g. to work on a file that's `,`-separated and one thats tab-separated in the same script you can use `awk 'script' FS=',' file1 FS='\t' file2`, or to identify the 2nd file rather than testing NR==FNR in the script you can use `awk 'script' file1 f=1 file2`). To use a file name that contains `=` you just have to specify the path to it, e.g. `x=7` is a variable assignment but `./x=7` is a file name. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001 for more info on initializing awk variables

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.  I'll give it all the consideration it deserves.

Comment: You're welcome. Nothing in my comment is an opinion though, it's all facts. If you think something I said is not a fact, please do let me know what and I'll clarify and/or provide examples and additional documentation.

Comment: Feel free to keep telling yourself that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if one of the strings you're searching for doesn't appear in the input you want to see it printed with a count of `0` rather than not printed at all, the robust, portable, efficient, concise way to do this is simply:

```
$ awk -F',' -v tgts='Want,Need' '
    { cnt[$8]++ }
    END { split(tgts,t); for (i in t) print t[i], cnt[t[i]]+0 }
' file
Want 1
Need 1
```

so it's hard to figure out where a regexp would come into play here. Maybe the following:

```
$ awk -F',' -v tgts='Want|Need' '
    $8 ~ ("^"tgts"$") { cnt[$8]++ }
    END { split(tgts,t,/[|]/); for (i in t) print t[i], cnt[t[i]]+0 }
' file
Want 1
Need 1
```

or:

```
$ awk -F',' -v tgts='Want|Need' '
    $0 ~ ("([^,]*,){7}"tgts"(,|$)") { cnt[$8]++ }
    END { split(tgts,t,/[|]/); for (i in t) print t[i], cnt[t[i]]+0 }
' file
Want 1
Need 1
```

but the regexps are just complicating the scripts and making them more fragile (the ones with regexps would fail if the strings you wanted to find contained regexp metachars like `.` or `*` while the first script would continue to work) and adding no value unless you have billions of unique `$8` values in your input.